# Is the Logitech Momo Force wheel compatible with the PS4?

Tags: ps4, hardware

I have found an old Logitech MOMO Force wheel.

[image: Racing wheel controller]

Will this one work with a PS4? Or is there any game, I could try it with. I don´t want to buy a game and then figure out that it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PS3 racing wheels aren't supported by the PS4, [it seems developers can write support drivers directly into their games](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2014-11-05-whats-the-deal-with-ps4-and-xbox-one-steering-wheels), but it doesn't seem any game has that funtionality right now.

[DriveClub currently supports two racing wheels](http://blog.us.playstation.com/2014/09/30/which-wheels-work-with-driveclub/). These are new wheels designed specifically with support the PS4 but they support the PS3 as well. These seem to be the only PS4 racing wheels available.

The Crew FAQ states that [If your steering wheel is supported by your PC/PS4/Xbox One then it should work for the game.](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/806230-The-Crew-Q-amp-A-November-2013-Forums). So I guess both of these wheels should work with it as well (Note: this FAQ was published in Nov 2013, things might've changed until the game's release.

NFS Rivals [doesn't seem to support racing wheels at all](http://community.eu.playstation.com/t5/PS4-General/Does-Need-For-Speed-Rivals-for-PS4-support-racing-wheels/m-p/20143243#M41736).

Answer (score 0):

Momo not working for PS4. 
But Thrustmaster T80, T100, T300 , T500 , Hori 4 they all work with PS4 (T100 and T500 work ok in gameplay only and not in the ps4 menu too)